# Required Attribute on a .NET API Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

In an API I found a response that has a field with the [Required] attribute on it. It is not a message being passed to the API but it is a response that the API is returning. Is there any reason for this and could it possibly be doing anything?

Comment: No. You can rid of it as long as the DTO/VIewModel is not used in POST action.

Comment: Possible: Yes. Likely: No. Why not ask the developer who added it?

Comment: He no longer works here

Comment: That attribute has no effect on outgoing models unless code has been written specifically for that purpose.

Comment: Alright thank you guys, I'm just removing it since only thing calling the API are mobile apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [[Required]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute is just there to specify that when a field on a form is validated, the field needs to contain a value. Meaning if the property happens to be null, contain an empty string or contain only white space characters, an exception will be thrown.

You could probably get away with getting rid of it but I don't see the need to touch anything. I would leave it as is if everything is working correctly.

Comment: So in this case the only thing calling the API are mobile apps

Answer (score 4):

Tools that generate client code that calls an API (like `AutoRest` and `swagger-codegen`) have been known to interpret a lack of `[Required]` on a response field as meaning that the field may be missing from response JSON (even if nullable=false for those fields).  This is especially true if they are generating TypeScript clients.  For this reason, I have had to actually add `[Required]` to most of my response properties.